# Docker: sending logs to localhost doesn't work but 0.0.0.0 does work, why?

Tags: networking, logging, docker, elastic-stack, docker-swarm

UPDATE: Now I have a problem. When a container was started before logstash the UDP logs do not arrive in logstash. According to this [bug report](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8795) this is because

> The linux kernel keeps state of each connection. Even though
>   udp is connectionless

as far as I understand it these connections are cached. Logstash receives a new IP and therefore no packages, this would not happen when I use localhost (instead of 0.0.0.0), as that IP never changes and docker forwards the messages to the exposed ports.

Any idea how I can make it work with localhost (or a service name since I am using docker swarm)?

---

I have a dockerized application (logstash) which publishes port 12201/udp to listen to logs. This accoring to the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#options)

> This binds port 8080 of the container to port 80 on 127.0.0.1 of the host machine.

However if I send messages with netcat to localhost:12201/udp the application receives nothing. Whereas when I send messages to 0.0.0.0:12201/udp everything works as intended.

**Why? Does this introduce performance/security issues? Could it be a bug?**

As far as I know 0.0.0.0 is translated to all ip addresses of the machine and the machine has its own ip address and some 172.*.0.* addresses/networks which docker creates according to [the docker container networking documentation.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/)

For some reason it seems that the published port is not mapped to localhost but some other network. I am running my application in a swarm and 0.0.0.0 works from any machine on the swarm.

---

Here the relevant part of my compose file:

```
networks:
  logging:

volumes:
    logging_data:

services:
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:5.3.1
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
    networks:
      - logging
    ports:
      - "12201:12201"
      - "12201:12201/udp"
    entrypoint: logstash -e 'input { gelf { } } output { stdout{ } elasticsearch { hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"] } }'
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch


    test:
    image: ubuntu
    networks:
      - logging
    logging:
      driver: gelf
      options:
        gelf-address: "udp://0.0.0.0:12201"
        tag: "log-test-tagi-docker"
    entrypoint: /bin/sh -c 'while true; do date +%H:%M:%S:%3N ; sleep 1; done'
    depends_on:
      - logstash
      - elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to avoid using 0.0.0.0. I now publish 127.0.0.1:12201:12201/udp. I can now use 127.0.0.1 from any machine in the swarm instead of 0.0.0.0. However port 12201 is still accessible from outside the swarm.

```
 logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:5.3.1
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
    networks:
      - logging
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:12201:12201/udp"
```

The problem that remains is that logs do not arrive after logstash is killed and restarted. That is because of conntrack tracking a connection (in linux) although udp is connectionless and should be possible to fix it as described [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8795).

I hope this helps someone with a similar issue.